# Will money fall from the sky if you pray for it?

Tags: tefilla, hashkafah-philosophy, money, miracle

If you daven for a parnasah and then just sit back will money come to you?

Comment: I'm yet to meet one person that didn't have to make any hishtadlus for parnassah..If anyone knows someone, let me know!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I agree with [YS](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/911) and would add if u were at that  level it would probably not fall from the sky, it will come in a way like finding money on the street or getting a raise/ promotion.

Comment: A source would make this answer much more valuable.

Answer (score 14):

If I daven for parnassah, probably not. However, for someone righteous enough, maybe, but it can come with a catch.

[Ta'anis 25a](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=1402&size=1) relates this story

> אמרה ליה דביתהו עד אימת ניזיל ונצטער כולי האי אמר לה מאי נעביד בעי רחמי דניתבו לך מידי בעא רחמי יצתה כמין פיסת יד ויהבו ליה חד כרעא דפתורא דדהבא (חזאי) בחלמא עתידי צדיקי דאכלי אפתורא דדהבא דאית ליה תלת כרעי (ואת) אוכלת אפתורא דתרי כרעי (אמרה ליה) ניחא לך דמיכל אכלי כולי עלמא אפתורא דמשלם ואנן אפתורא דמחסר אמרה ליה ומאי נעביד בעי רחמי דנשקלינהו מינך בעי רחמי ושקלוהו תנא גדול היה נס אחרון יותר מן הראשון

(my summary):

Rabbi Chanina's wife asked him how much longer they would have to suffer in poverty, and she told him to pray for something to be given to them.

So Rabbi Chanina prayed, and a miracle occured - a hand appeared and gave him a gold table-leg.

Afterwards, he saw in a dream that in Olam Haba they would have a table with only two legs instead of the three-legged table that everyone else had. So he told his wife this and she made him give it back (which was a bigger miracle).

Comment: This is similar to the story of R' Shim'on bar Yochai and the valley of gold dinars, and even more so to the story of R' Shim'on ben Chalafta and the jewel from heaven ([*Tanchuma*, *Pikudei*](https://books.google.com/books?id=mlYMAQAAIAAJ&pg=RA2-PA131#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

Answer (score 6):

No, but if you work the minimum amount and devote yourself to the service of God more and more, then the amount of exertion that you will need to do will diminish down to zero.

[Chovos Halevavos Shaar Habitachon middle of chapter 3](http://dafyomireview.com/article.php?docid=380#ch3):

> If a man strengthens himself in the service of G-d, chooses to fear G-d, trusts in Him on matters of torah and matters of this world, steers away from bad things and desires good midot (character traits), does not rebel in times of plenty, does not turn towards leisure, does not follow his evil inclination, is not enticed by the witchery of this world - the burden of earning a livelihood will be removed from him, since the two reasons mentioned above no longer apply to him, namely, to test him on his choice and to see if he will rebel during prosperity. His livelihood will come to him without effort or difficulty, according to his needs, as written "G-d will not bring hunger to the righteous" (Mishlei 10:3).

Comment: the Hovot Halevavot does not state explicitly that _no_ effort will be necessary. Certainly it is difficult to infer this from what is quite possibly a translation, of a translation (of a translation?)

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to do Histadlus, each person according to the spiritual level the person is holding.

Comment: A source would make this answer much more valuable.

Comment: You are getting a big Mahloket Rabenu Behaye and Ramban.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible however it is not likely. Most of us are not on that level of Bitachon.

Comment: A source would make this answer much more valuable.

Answer (score -2):

About good things falling from the sky - manna is the first that comes to mind; buew it was delivered without prayer.

Personally, I have not seen money fall from the sky; have you heard of such a thing?

When a person prays for money to fall from the sky, what might they be thinking of?
If to enrich themselves in order to provide better for the family, then anything that happens suddenly and wholly unexpected, such as a surprise offer of a well paying job, then their prayer was answered.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Holly Glaser. Thanks for your perspective, but I don't see that this actually answers the question, which asks whether money will come to a person due only to prayer. You indicate that if it does then the prayer was answered, but not whether that can happen.